# What would cause ORA-00942?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-view

I just created a `view` on `oracle 11g` but when i try to query it, i get this error :

> **ORA-00942:** *table or view does not exist.*

I know the view was created successfully because i can see it in the view folder. Anyone have any suggestions on what the issue might be?

Comment: are you sure you're still connected to the same schema(user) where you created the view..?

Comment: perhaps you may try to recreate and then issue `SQL>show err` command.

Comment: The issue might be caused by missing grants on the used views, tables or functions in the view. The creator of the view might have all rights to do so, but on the query there might be missing some grants - try to perform the query of the view directly and see if you also get the error there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I had created a view with double quotes on the name of the view. removing the double quotes resolved the issue